# Visual Studio 2010 powertools HTML clipboard support

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, clipboard, visual-studio-power-tools

I installed http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/09/visual-studio-2010-productivity-power-tool-extensions.aspx but I can not find where I can make use of the HTML clipboard support. Anyone knows where to find it? I already searched in the kebyoard settings after Copy but that didn't provide me something useful.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try out the steps described in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kirillosenkov/copy-code-in-html-format-with-visual-studio-2010)?

You need to do the following:

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>
2. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> (paste special), not normal paste!

Answer (score 1):

when you copy the code and paste it to a HTML buffer (i.e visual studio designer) it will be automatically formatted.

to try it

copy a code and paste it in visual studio HTML designer 
you will find it automatically formatted.

Comment: I am not looking for pasting html code in Visual Studio but take html code from Visual Studio and paste it in for example Windows Live Writer.

Comment: @NylaPareska Not sure it's possible. What I do is paste it to a new HTML document in Visual Studio, paste it there as HTML and copy it. (You don't need to save an HTML document before typing, so it's pretty quick. Quicker with the shortcut Ctrl + N, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Just for possible future readers of this (as I came here from Google myself).

For me, `ctrl`+`shift`+`v` is not doing anything in Windows Live Writer 2011.

However, when I right click in the designer I find the "Paste Special" option, and it gets me the following dialog:

[image]

And then the rest of the article works, choosing "Keep Formatting" gets me the code as expected.

Another tip is don't mess with the Power Tools Copy HTML Tools->Options dialog settings that mention `span` in them. The 'use classes' option doesn't work and you have to use inline styles. The setting that did work for me was replacing space characters (Default `&nbsp;`) with real space  no more. This works because the default code container is `<pre>` tag which "does" preserve spaces. Of course this won't work if you change the container to something else that doesn't have `<pre>`.